# Is it possible to work with Apple Keychain from Kotlin in KMM?

Tags: ios, kotlin, keychain, kmm

Basically the whole question is in the title: "**Is it possible to work with Apple Keychain from Kotlin in KMM?**"

I found there is available `platform.Security` for `iosMain` module but it contains constants only. There is a nothing like `SecItemAdd` and so on.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_in_the_keychain) is a tutorial how to work with **Apple Keychain** and I try to find a way to make it from Kotlin side.

Is it possible?

Comment: `import platform.Security.SecItemAdd` works fine to me

Comment: @PylypDukhov, OMG, thank you very much! It was imported successfully. I don't know why but I could not find it by navigation in Android Studio

Comment: You're welcome. I always start with a GitHub search like [this](https://github.com/search?type=Code&l=kotlin&q=SecItemAdd) in such cases to see wether it was used by anyone else =)

Comment: @PylypDukhov, to be honest, I didn't use it before. Thank you for advice, I'll follow it